# ssh fails with ssh_dispatch_run_fatal invalid format

Tags: ssh

During the last years I've had various problems with MacOS SSH, but those were quickly resolved searching the net. This is now something different.

This is Mojave -system with lates updates (10.14.4). I do think though that this did begin even before updating with the latest patches.

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

The error I get is:

```
$ ssh <host> -v
---8<----
debug1: no key from blob. pkalg ssh-rsa: invalid format
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to <host> port 22: invalid format
```

I've tried running without defined config-file, running with different options, but with no help.  From other systems, such as Arch Linux (OpenSSH_7.9p1) and CentOS7 (OpenSSH_7.4p1) ssh'ing to the same host works well. Especially the same SSH version working on an arch linux tells me that this is something apple-related.

So what is happening now and how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like your key is corrupt - https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format.

Comment: Is there a way to force authentication *without* a key? Other than moving that away from the .ssh-directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error sounds like your SSH key may be corrupt. This SF Q&A titled: [SSH Suddenly returning Invalid format](https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format)
 mentions it as well with that same conclusion.

Your options are to either regenerate a new SSH key or try connecting using just your username + password.

#### Force SSH password method

To force SSH to use the password method for establishing a connection you can use this alias like so:

```
$ alias sshno='ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o ControlPath=none'
```

You can then connect to servers with your username + password:

```
$ sshno <user>@<server>
```

#### Problem with SSH key length

In more recent versions of OSX Apple decided to drop support for keys that were < 2048 bits in length. This was apparently done with the migration to Sierra as discussed in this article titled: [Upgrading to macOS Sierra will break your SSH keys and lock you out of your own servers](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/upgrading-to-macos-sierra-will-break-your-ssh-keys-and-lock-you-out-of-your-own-servers-f413ac96139a).

You can verify your SSH key-pair's length like so:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/ssh_slm@keynum1_id_rsa.pub
4096 SHA256:mwvSCr2CO5RXjML2EhgERTHgGB23JgRegB23Th34aeT slm@somedom.com (RSA)
```

This shows that my key's length is 4096 bits. You can generate a SSH key-pair with a specific length by using the `-b` switch to `ssh-keygen`.

```
$ ssh-keygen -b 4096 ....
```

Comment: That answered my questions. The key, either locally or at the target host, seems to be the problem. Keylength is 4096, if that interests somebody. Thanks slm

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your keys are corrupted, as this issue is seen after some [hardware failures](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/got-scrambled-text-in-ssh-randomly.55395/). Try backing up and removing `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` and generating the missing keys with `ssh-keygen -A`.